# How Do You Go From One Screen, Clear It Then Go To A New Screen In Python Turtle?

Tags: rest

So Basically, I am trying To Make A Screen, Make A Menu, Then Go Onto Another Screen Were The Actual Fun Happens. Help!

Answer (score 0):

## You mean this?

```
import turtle
#import time

screen1 = turtle.Screen()
#screen1.bgcolor('red')
#time.sleep(5)
screen1.clearscreen()
screen2 = turtle.Screen()
#screen2.bgcolor('blue')
```